# Setting corner radius without clipsToBounds works only for UIView type?

Tags: ios, uiview, label, layer, cornerradius

I have a UIView for which I set a cornerRadius property alone. The UIView updates its corners. But say I have a UILabel for which I set cornerRadius property alone without clipsToBounds, it does not work. Both are of type UIView, then why does it not work for UILabel

Answer (score 2):

***Internally***, `UILabel` has more than one **layer**... `UIView` does not.

You can use either:

```
myLabel.clipsToBounds = true
```

or

```
myLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
```